# Recover Linux Mint HDD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, terminal, data-recovery, linux-mint

I have an HDD that doesn't work anymore. It was working fine, but the OS was lagged and the user turned off the computer using the power button, after that the bios doesn't recognize the HD anymore.

So I'm trying to get some files from it.
I'm using a Linux Mint to try to see the files in the HD, and using an adaptor to make SATA to USB. When I connect the HD in my computer in `dmesg` I see the lines

```
[fev20 15:55] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 access beyond end of device
[  +0,000012] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x1000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  +0,000027] EXT4-fs (sdb): unable to read superblock
[ +23,127307] usb 2-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 4
[fev20 15:56] usb 2-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  +0,117313] usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2338, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  +0,000008] usb 2-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[  +0,000003] usb 2-1.5: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge
[  +0,000002] usb 2-1.5: Manufacturer: JMicron
[  +0,000002] usb 2-1.5: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[  +0,000589] usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  +0,002563] scsi host6: usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0
[  +1,020394] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access                                    PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[  +0,000441] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  +0,000743] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  +0,000378] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 72057594037927936 512-byte logical blocks: (36.9 EB/32.0 EiB)
[  +0,000979] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  +0,000006] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[  +0,001362] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  +0,000007] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  +0,005867] sdb: detected capacity change from 0 to 72057594037927936
[  +0,000013] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

But I cannot access the HD. If I use `fdisk` I get:

```
Disco /dev/sda: 465,76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 setores
Disk model: WDC WD5000BPKT-0
Unidades: setor de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamanho de setor (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tamanho E/S (mínimo/ótimo): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tipo de rótulo do disco: gpt
Identificador do disco: 55C2D15A-9665-47C1-B6AA-B6A40F70BA08

Dispositivo  Início       Fim   Setores Tamanho Tipo
/dev/sda1      2048      4095      2048      1M BIOS inicialização
/dev/sda2      4096   1054719   1050624    513M Sistema EFI
/dev/sda3   1054720 976771071 975716352  465,3G Linux sistema de arquivos
```

That is my main HD.

How Can I acces the `sdb`? I cannot mount it, because it give me some erros

```
anderson@andersonHp:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /home/pendrive/
mount: /home/pendrive: can't read superblock on /dev/sdb.
```

I don't know what to do.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: If it's no longer recognized by the firmware it's probably dead. Don't waste your time.

Comment: Today I tried to connect the HD via SATA and it gets recognized but with 0 gb :'). I think it's really dead, but I'll try a little more..